# Identifying Ba'alei Tosafos

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, rabbis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is the voice of Tosafoth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/who-is-the-voice-of-tosafoth)

How much do we know about which specific people wrote which comments of *[Tosafos](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/TalmudMap/Tosafot.html)*?