# Who is the voice of Tosafoth?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, rabbis, text, tosfot

Tosafoth were the sons-in-law, grandchildren, and students of Rashi (and their students), and "they" wrote a commentary on the Talmud that is often at odds with Rashi's earlier commentary.  Sometimes there are internal disagreements within a single commentary on the passage of Talmud being discussed.  Who is the redactor of the various opinions expressed in the commentary of Tosafoth?

Comment: Actually, most of the tractates that can be identified are the redaction of the school at Touques, headed by Rabbi Eliezer. They're based mainly upon the schools of Evreux and Sens, the latter being both a revision of and an addition to the Tosafot of the Ri haZaken ("Tosafot Yeshenim"). This is the reason why Rabbeinu Tam and the Ri feature so prominently, even in those tractates that owe their origin to different schools.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33705

Answer (score 11):

There is a sefer by [Efraim Urbach](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0411/is_n3_v42/ai_14234266/?tag=content;col1) called ["Ba'alei HaTosafot"](https://www.bialik-publishing.co.il/Tosafot-Urbach) (in Hebrew) that discusses them and analyzes, *Masechta* by *Masechta*, who the anonymous authors might be.

Comment: *Administrative note: This answer was posted to another question and merged hither.*

Comment: Just as an endorsement, I have the sefer and it is definitely worth the purchase if you are trying to understand the development of Jewish teaching in Provence and Tzarfat. When read in conjunction with other history books like, Seder HaDorot, it gives a completely fresh, new view of the transmission of Torah.

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia's article "Tosafot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot), quoting [the 1906 Jewish Encyclopedia's](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14457-tosafot):

> The edited tosafot owe their existence particularly to Samson of Sens
>   and to the following French tosafists of the thirteenth century: (1)
>   Moses of Évreux, (2) Eliezer of Touques, and (3) Perez ben Elijah of
>   Corbeil.

Answer (score 6):

Following @Yahu's suggestion, I'll summarize [Urbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Urbach)'s analysis of the editors of the tosfot of the different masechtot:

- **Brachot** - An unknown Ashkenazi (Germanic) scholar who personally knew
  [Rabbi Moshe of Evreux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_of_%C3%89vreux), but was probably not his student. The tosfot
  are mostly based on the writings of [Rabbi Yehudah Messer Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Isaac_Messer_Leon).
- **Shabbat** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), combining the tosfot of [Rabbi
  Yosef Porat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85811/20472) and the [RaSh of Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Eruvin** - A student of [Rabbi Yitzchak of Dampierre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Abraham_of_Dampierre) (the Ritzva),
  combining a multitude of different tosfot.
- **Pesachim** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), mostly based on [Tosfot Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens),
  with additions from other sources.
- **Yoma** - The [Maharam of Rothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg), mostly based on the writings of the
  students of [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel).
- **Sukkah** - [RaSh of Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens), based on writings of the students of [Rabbeinu
  Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam).
- **Beitzah** - A student or students of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), mostly a
  combination of [Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens) and Evreux.
- **Rosh Hashanah** - [RaSh of Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Taanit** - Probably a student of Rabbi Yitzchak of Tresson, mostly
  based on Rabbi Yitzchak and Rabbi Yitzchak's rabbi, Ri of Melon's
  teachings.
- **Megillah** - [Rabbi Yehudah Messer Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Isaac_Messer_Leon), who also combined tosfot from
  his contemporaries, such as [Rabbi Elchanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elhanan_ben_Isaac_of_Dampierre), son of the [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel).
- **Mo'ed Katan** - Rabbi Shmuel, son of [Rabbi Elchanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elhanan_ben_Isaac_of_Dampierre) and grandson of [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel),
  mostly based on the teachings of Rabbi Yitzchak ben Rabbi Mordechai,
  student of the Riva, and those of Rabbi Avraham, student of the
  Rashba.
- **Chagigah** - Probably [Rabbi Moshe of Evreux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_of_%C3%89vreux), mostly based on those of
  [Rabbi Yehudah Messer Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Isaac_Messer_Leon), with two sections by [Rabbi Shimon of
  Yunebeil](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%22%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%9F#%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95) and some additions from [Rabbi Elchanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elhanan_ben_Isaac_of_Dampierre) and others.
- **Yevamot** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), using a multitude of different
  sources.
- **Ketubot** - Likely [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), mostly based on [RaSh of
  Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Kiddushin** - A student of [Rabbi Yitzchak of Evreux](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8168-isaac-of-evreux), bringing mostly
  teachings of the rabbis of Evreux.
- **Gittin** - Unknown. Based mostly on tosfot of Touques or those of [Rabbi
  Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques).
- **Nedarim** - A student of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), based mostly on teachings
  from Evreux.
- **Nazir** - A student of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), based mostly on
  teachings from Evreux.
- **Sotah** - Possibly a student of the rabbis of Speyer, or perhaps he was
  [Rabbi Baruch ben Shmuel of Mainz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_ben_Samuel).
- **Bava Kama** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), mostly based on the tosfot of
  [Rabbi Yehudah Messer Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Isaac_Messer_Leon).
- **Bava Metzia** - A nephew of [Rabbi Chizkiyah of Magdeburg](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%93%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92) (who was also
  the uncle of [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), though this editor is not
  him).
- **Bava Batra** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), based mostly on [Rabbeinu Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam)
  and [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel).
- **Avodah Zara** - A student of [Rabbienu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), mostly based on
  the teachings of [Rabbi Shmuel of Falaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ben_Solomon_of_Falaise).
- **Sanhedrin** - A student of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), mostly based on [Tosfot
  Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Makot** - A student of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), mostly based on [Tosfot Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Shvuot** - [Rabbi Eliezer of Touques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_of_Touques), mostly based on the tosfot of
  [Rabbi Elchanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elhanan_ben_Isaac_of_Dampierre) and those of [Rabbi Moshe of Evreux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_of_%C3%89vreux).
- **Horayot** - An unknown Ashkenazi (Germanic) editor, based mostly on
  [Rabbi Simcha of Speyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simha_of_Speyer).
- **Zevachim** - [Rabbi Baruch of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_ben_Isaac) and a student of his, based on the
  writings of several students of [Rabbeinu Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam) and [Tosfot Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Menachot** - [RaSh of Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens) with some later edits by his students.
- **Chullin** - A student of [Rabbi Aharon of Regensburg](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%91%22%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95), mostly based on
  Tosfot Touques.
- **Bechorot** - Rabbi Yitzchak, student of Rabbi Baruch. Mostly based on
  [Tosfot Sens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens).
- **Erchin** - Possibly a student of the son of Rabbi Shmuel, also possibly
  a student of Rabbi Mordechai Halevi or the [Maharam of Rothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg),
  based on a variety of sources.
- **Temurah** - A student of Rabbi Shmuel of Evreux and "Maharar", which is
  likely either Rabbi Mordechai Halevi or the [Maharam of Rothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg).
- **Kritot** - A student of [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel) and [Rabbi Chaim Kohen](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_(%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA)), based on a variety of
  Ashkenazi (Germanic) teachings.
- **Me'illah** - A student of [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah), based mostly on teachings of
  [Rabbeinu Peretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peretz_ben_Elijah).
- **Kinim** - An unknown Ashkenazi (Germanic) editor, based on Ashkenazi (Germanic)
  sources.
- **Niddah** - An unknown editor, based mostly on Tosfot Touques.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the Tosfot commentary for a particular masechet was compiled by a particular Tosafist. Based on clues ranging from outright self identification to alignment of particular shitot, rulings, we can identify a large majority of the authors.

Comment: *Administrative note: This answer was posted to another question and merged hither.*

Answer (score 2):

there are many different tosafot on each meseches some of the more famous ones are

1. tosafot harosh
2. tosafot ri"d
3. tosafot rabeinu peretz
4. tosafot tuch (most common alongside gemorah )
5. tosafot harashb"a meshantz
6. tosafot rabbeinu moshe

there may be as many as 20 on any given mesechet

when the gemorah was published they printed whatever tosafot was available, and most commonly used, on each mesechet by itself.(this also has alot to do with the fact books were hand-written so most commonly used was usually the most availiable) usually the most well written, concise, and compact on that mesechet was considered best. there are many instances which some meforshim say 2 different tosafists are printed a just few pages from one another. (theres a quite few such instances in the first few pages of pesachim)