# Authors of Daat Zkeinim

Tags: jewish-books, tosfot, authorship, commentaries

My question is very simple and straightforward: does anybody know who authored the Torah commentary, *Daat Zkeinim* (דעת זקנים)? I know that it was written by some of the Baalei haTosafot, but would very much like to know who.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, Rabbeinu Tam is one I believe. There is a Daas Zekeinim on the words, ["Vayifga bamokom etc"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=33587&st=%u05d5%u05d9%u05e4%u05d2%u05e2) which fits with Rabbeinu Tam's view about early Maariv in [Gem. Brochos d.h. mai-aimosai](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17347/1569

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20791&st=&pgnum=533&hilite=), the author is unknown. However, [earlier in the book](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20791&st=&pgnum=8) (fn. 2), he says that it was first printed in [Livorno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livorno) 5543, if that helps you.