# Tosfos Within the Same Mesechta

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, tosfot

Are the comments of Tosfos in the same Mesechta generally considered to be aligned, meaning that, if there is an apparent contradiction, we try and look for a resolution?

How about Tosfos in different Mesechtas?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17347

Comment: @msh210 I think Yahu's answer there works here too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is the voice of Tosafoth?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/who-is-the-voice-of-tosafoth)

Comment: @WAF yes I agree with you, I just saw that question, looked up the sefer that Yahu says, hopefully will get to reading it soon, however just at a quick glance, he has a chapter where he goes through the different Tosfos authors by Mesechta and identifies (at least Meseches Berachos, which is what I was learning) as having one author/editor.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol15Leibowitz.pdf

Comment: @Efraim, related, but not a duplicate. There could be different answers to this question for any given answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

I recall a place in Bava Kamma where R' Akiva Eiger points out that Tosfos in two different chapters are clearly saying opposite things -- and we just assume that was due to two different authors/editors.

Comment: Does "we" mean R'AE?

Comment: that happens a lot, I'll just give one more example the second gilyon hashas on daf 2. berachos, and meforshim on him explain how their is no contradiction between the tosfos, so that is not a conclusive proof